# Crontab message ...killed when starting server

Tags: java, linux, cron

I was starting my server using crontab. The problem is the server started successfully however I was getting a message such as `l 26606 Killed`. Please advice what is this message for and what will be the impact.

Comment: Can you give us more informations ? The server killed contrab process ?
Can you copy/past the log message ?

Comment: i cant open or copy the message log as i dont have root access.

Comment: Hard to tell what you mean, posting a log would give us a better hint.

Comment: thanks. i finding other alternatives